# How to create a simple RP in Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: c#, wcf, single-sign-on, wif

I have done following steps-

```
1. Created a website using VS2012.
2. Configute Authorization in config file show that only logded in user can access the 
   resources. 
   I am using asp.net DefaultMembershipProvider for testing purpose.
3. Run the site & Register a user & logded in to site.
4. Now added local STS by clicking "Identity and Access"
5. It has modified the config file to use WIF Federation Authentication.
```

Now when i run the site it automatically logded in and show 'Terry' as logded in user. When i click on logoff link does not happen anything.

After lookiing into project found that 'Terry' is automatically logded in from cliam section of LocalSTS.exe.config.

Is there any practical use of cliam section of LocalSTS.exe.config?

Simply i want to create two RP Site & one STS. Both RP site will be authenticated by STS & provide SSO. Each RP site uses their own membership data to authenticate user.

Can anybody please provide me to steps to do this. Most of the example i have read shows using cliam section of LocalSTS.exe.config.

Thanks,

@SAM

Answer (score 0):

LocalSTS just provides a "canned" claim. It's used for testing. You can alter these claims by editing the XML.

In the real world you need a proper STS like ADFS. However, that authenticates against AD.

The point of a STS is that it authenticates against a single repository. It's the STS that does the authentication, not the RP.

To do what you want to do involves having two STS, one for each repository and then federating them.